# Why isn't the module shown as updated?

Tags: 8, composer

I updated a module with Composer and it shows updated in the composer.json file.
However, on *Available updates*, it still shows the old version is installed. I ran update.php and nothing changed.

Drupal core is updated and the module needs to be updated to work with the core version.

Why isn't the module shown as updated? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What commands did you use to update? Did you get any message back, maybe a dependency that is not met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have multiple instances of the module in different places in your codebase. You may want to try a `find . -type d -name MODULE_NAME` from your project root and see what turns up.

Comment: I had to rebuild this site with composer because the group that built it at first did not use composer at all. There were modules in the modules/ folder and modules/contrib folder.